# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.at deleteTodo

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, backend

I'm trying to do a basic delete todo method without succeeding. I don't know why I get this error hope for help.
Error:
(node:6416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
at deleteTodo

Code:

```js
const deleteTodo = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.body;
  DUMMY_PLACES = DUMMY_PLACES.filter((p) => p.id !== id);
  res.status(200).json({ message: "Deleted " });
};
```

DUMMY_DB

```js
const DUMMY_PLACES = [
  {
    id: 01,
    todo: "thats my first test to do",
    enable: false,
  },
  {
    id: 02,
    todo: "thats my second test to do",
    enable: false,
  },
  {
    id: 03,
    todo: "thats my third test to do",
    enable: false,
  },
];
```

The DELETE request in postman:

```js
{
    "id": 3
}
```

Comment: "*Assignment to constant variable*"–`DUMMY_PLACES` is a constant variable.

Answer (score 1):

`const` forbids reassigning a value to the defined variable, which you do with:

```
DUMMY_PLACES = DUMMY_PLACES.filter((p) => p.id !== id);
```

Use `let` instead of `const` if you want to do that kind of operation, like:

```
let DUMMY_PLACES = ...
```

Comment: bro you right I'm so dumb sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are writing these code for the `node` back-end. Then you should specify the route where delete method is handled, like:

app.delete('/', async (req,res) => {//your delete logic} )

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that OP tries to change the value of a constant variable.

Comment: right, yes my fault